# How would I solve for the Taylor series for cos(x$^{1/2}$) centered at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How would I solve for the Taylor series :
**cos(x$^{1/2}$)** centered at **x=0**?

Answer (score 1):

Take the Taylor series for $\cos(u)$ and plug in $u = x^{1/2}$.